# Alternative to RLE for short, infrequent runs

Tags: javascript, compression, url

I have 3 number arrays that I need to encode into a URL through query parameters. Example:

```
http://localhost:3000/?r=133223333302302040&y=10000000000000000000&b=13333332002100122331
```

This is a React app, and each number array represents a part of the apps state. The URL in its entirety represents the underlying state of the entire app, and it is through the URL that users communicate saved state to other users

I'm looking for ways to make the URL as short as possible without resorting to running a database for URL shortening

I thought of using RLE (run-length encoding), and while that will work well for the second array, the 1st and 3rd arrays contain runs that are infrequent, and surrounded by single digit "non-runs". In those cases, RLE will actually result in a longer string

I was thinking theres a way to use a token character to represent a shortened run, so maybe something like `133223333302302040` -> `133225x302302040`where `5x3` represents 5 lots of the character `3`. It gets around the problem of having to encode "non-runs", but doesnt end up saving too much space in the end...

Are there any alternatives to RLE that will guarantee a shorter encoded string in this type of situation? The result must be URL safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compression is the wrong thing to use here. If your original way of encoding application state should be as dense as possible, then it should no longer be possible to compress the encoded text any smaller. I'd suggest reading into [Shannon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem) [entropy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) for the mathematical details.

Now you have two choices of encoding, you can use fixed length encoding scheme here, which is best if you know that all application states are equally likely. Or you can use a variable length encoding system if you know that certain application state are much more likely to happen than other things.

With fixed length encoding, you'll represent your application state into a bit string. You'd then encode this bit string into a dense encoding like Base64 or Base85, or whatever the densest encoding system your transmission system allows. The advantage of fixed encoding is that it's simple and have predictable sizes; but it doesn't take advantage of many types of redundancy in the system.

The other strategy is variable length encoding. Variable length encoding are beneficial when certain applications states are much more likely to happen than some other ones, so they're assigned with shorter encodings. The flip side to this is that application states that are much less likely to happen would actually increase in size. The trick to variable length encoding is to correctly identify which states (or classes of states) should be encoded with the shortest length, so that most of the actual data that typical users see will actually have the shortest codes. Well designed variable encoding can give you much smaller encodings in practice than fixed length encoding, but they're also much more complex to design and there's a potential that they can actually increase the size with pathological data for the encoding.

RLE falls under the latter type of encoding. Most general purpose compression algorithms are variable length encoding, and will actually increase the compressed data size when compressing random data with no patterns/repetition to exploit.

To design a variable length encoding, you need to know the statistical distribution of the application states. Since you didn't describe what your application state string represents, this question is not answerable in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 0-9 but you have A–Z, a–z, 0–9 etc. available. Please look into [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding and URL safe variants thereof.

If your application state is modeled in a struct or object, you can look into serialization aspects of [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/) or [gRPC](https://grpc.io/).

Other than that, it really depends on how many actual application states you have. From there, you can think about what tokens can be sent to represent them.